# Java Formatter specify starting position for text

Tags: java, printf, formatter

I'm trying to position a string at a certain starting position on a line, regardless of where the previous text ended. For instance:

```
Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --all                  do not ignore entries starting with .
  -A, --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..
```

The explanation of the options begin at position 30 regardless of the text preceding. How do you accomplish this with java.util.Formatter? I have tested with both the width (`%30s`) and precision (`%.30`) arguments, and neither provide the desired result.

Comment: If you used Apache Commons CLI, all of this would be done for you, including parsing of option arguments, and formatting of help text (http://commons.apache.org/cli/)

Comment: The question isn't about parsing options necessarily.

Comment: @dplass: That's why I didn't post it as an answer. But if parsing and formatting arguments is the end goal, there's no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ 'width' parameter, like this:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%-30s%s", "  -a, --all", "do not ignore entries starting with ."));
    System.out.println(String.format("%-30s%s", "  -A, --almost-all", "do not list implied . and .."));
```

**edit**
Complete overview, if you're interested. It's not big at all, formatting functionality is quite limited.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: thank you! Left-justifying the previous formatter is what I was looking for. I've read through the javadocs and the answer wasn't occurring to me.